# Checking for database existence with Phing

Tags: php, ant, phing, ant-contrib

I'd like to do something like the following in my Phing **build.xml**:

```
<if>
    <not>
        <dbexists dsn="mysql:host=${database.host}" username="${database.username}" password="${database.password}" database="${database.name}"/>
    </not>
    <then>
        <pdosqlexec url="mysql:host=${database.host}" userid="${database.username}" password="${database.password}">
            CREATE DATABASE ${database.name};
        </pdosqlexec>        
        <pdosqlexec url="mysql:host=${database.host};dbname=${database.name}" userid="${database.username}" password="${database.password}">
            <transaction src="create-database-schema.sql"/>
        </pdosqlexec>
    </then>
</if>
```

Unfortunately I can't think of any way that this would be possible. A **dbexists** task obviously doesn't exist and it's impossible to create a custom condition.

The only remaining possibility is to create a custom task which (in PHP) checks for the existence of the database and returns 'Yes' or 'No', which can be assigned into a property and used in a Phing condition. Problem is, I don't know if that's even possible; I can't see anything in the documentation about assigning a property from within a custom task and Google isn't helping either.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4903695/256618

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be able to use the `<trycatch>` Task for that.

```
<trycatch property="error">
    <try>
        <pdosqlexec url="mysql:host=${host}" userid="${username}" password="${pw}">
            CREATE DATABASE ${database.name};
        </pdosqlexec>
    </try>
    <catch>
        <echo message="${error}" />
    </catch>
</trycatch>
```